# multiple row in cvs export via php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

These codes works properly displaying two rows and multiple columns of data,
but I want to display addtitional text headers in additional rows

the current code display like:

DATA ID | USER ID | OFFICE 
1       | 1       | DO

I want something like

REPORT IN INVENTORY
DATE
DATA ID | USER ID | OFFICE
1       | 1       | DO

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['exp'])) {   
$wpdb->show_errors(); 
global $wpdb;

// Grab any post values you sent with your submit function
$DownloadReportFrom = "ReportDateFrom";
$DownloadReportTo = "ReportDateFrom";

// Build your query                     
$MyQuery = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_rpci_rpci');

$result = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT sum(balancepercard) as result_value     FROM wp_rpci_rpci');
$total = $result[0]->result_value;  


// Process report request
if (! $MyQuery) {
$Error = $wpdb->print_error();
die("The following error was found: $Error");
} else {
// Prepare our csv download

// Set header row values
$csv_fields=array();
$csv_fields[] = 'DATA ID';
$csv_fields[] = 'USER ID';
$csv_fields[] = 'OFFICE';
$csv_fields[] = 'ARTICLE';
$csv_fields[] = 'DESCRIPTION';
$csv_fields[] = 'STOCK NUMBER';
$csv_fields[] = 'UNIT OF MEASURE';
$csv_fields[] = 'UNIT VALUE';
$csv_fields[] = 'BALANCE PER CARD';
$csv_fields[] = 'ONHAND PER COUNT';
$csv_fields[] = 'S/O QUANTITY';
$csv_fields[] = 'S/O VALUE';
$csv_fields[] = 'REMARKS';
$csv_fields[] = '';
$csv_fields[] = 'TOTAL BALANCE: '.$total.'';


$output_filename = 'MyReport_' . $DownloadReportFrom .'-'. $DownloadReportTo  . '.csv';
$output_handle = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );

header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
header( 'Content-type: text/csv' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $output_filename );
header( 'Expires: 0' );
header( 'Pragma: public' ); 

// Insert header row
fputcsv( $output_handle, $csv_fields );

// Parse results to csv format
foreach ($MyQuery as $Result) {
$leadArray = (array) $Result; // Cast the Object to an array
// Add row to file
fputcsv( $output_handle, $leadArray );
}

// Close output file stream
fclose( $output_handle ); 

die();
}
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your code with:

```
// Insert header row(S)
fputcsv( $output_handle, array('REPORT IN INVENTORY') );
fputcsv( $output_handle, array('DATE') );
fputcsv( $output_handle, $csv_fields );
```

this should add the 2 fields you want at the top

Comment: Thank you so much that's perfect :D

Comment: @genesilva great please read how to accpet answers: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers